# Laravel Eloquent key mapping

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am looking for a simple way to change/standardize the keys that are returned from Eloquent. At this point, my application and database are quite old. I am building a new set of API's to interact with the data, but changing the database is simply not an option. As an alternative, I'd simply like to map the field names on my select queries.

Take the given response as it is currently returned:

```
[
    'companyrecordid': 1234,
    'clientid': 2345,
    'name': 'Some cool company',
    'street_address': '1234 N. Nowhere'
]
```

The desired outcome would be:

```
[
    'id': 1234,
    'clientId': 2345,
    'name': 'Some cool company',
    'streetAddress': '1234 N. Nowhere'
]
```

In an ideal world, it would be amazing if this was as simple as adding a variable to my model... something like:

```
protected static $keymap = [
    'companyrecordid' => 'id',
    'clientid' => 'clientId',
    'street_address' => 'streetAddress',
];
```

If nothing exists like, this, I would not be opposed to writing it myself, I just don't want to re-invent the wheel if there is no reason to do so.

Comment: Fractal! http://fractal.thephpleague.com/

Comment: I found, or rather was directed at fractal, I am playing with it now. It seems pretty heavy for something that should be, in theory, simple. Pre-laravel, I would have just done something like: 'SELECT companyrecordid as id, clientid as clientId...'

Comment: Well, there's nothing preventing you from specifying aliases in an eloquent select clause if that's what you prefer.

Comment: If you are using Laravel 5, there's this Mappable, https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Mappable

Answer (score 1):

You can use mutators to do this name conversion https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Sure, but it seems that mutators are simply for getting and setting values, what about when you are simply returning a collection from the controller for the sake of an API response?

Comment: This is the official way to do it. Alternatively, you could also have your own little transformation utility that uses `array_map()` to rename the keys. Do not introduce an external library just for this usecase.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks Macros are your answer. Since you are building an API, you will be returning mostly JSON responses so no need for Eloquent here. There wont be any model manipulation in the views.

In `App/Providers` create a service. I call it here KeyMapServiceProvider.

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class KeyMapServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
     public function boot()
     {
         Response::macro('keymaps', function ($old) {
             $new = (object)[
                 'id' => $old->companyrecordid,
                 'clientId' => $old->clientid,
                 'street_address' => $old->streetAddress,
             ];
             return Response::make($new);
         });
     }
}
```

Then anywhere in your app

```
$data = DB::table('data')->get();
return response()->keymaps($data);
```

You may have to tweak a few things. But that's most of it here. 
Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#response-macros

Comment: Very interesting answer Eddy.